# How to best do unit testing for a web application

Tags: unit-testing

I am writing a web application that is very complex in terms of UI and relies heavily on AJAX, DOM and image manipulations.

Is there any standard practice (I don't want tools) which can be followed to reduce the bugs?

Comment: Great Question.  I've been wondering the same thing.

Comment: This is a very vague question. Your question could normally be answered with a list of tools, but you make it sound like there is some magical way to get less bugs in your code. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @ryeguy His question is a design oriented question. He's asking how the Unit Testing style fits in with a heavily UI app. Carlten was able to answer that.

Comment: I think devinb is correct.Also tools help you to find bugs, but how do u reduce them in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate the logic and the UI portions - do not have all your business logic and complex code in the code behind page. Instead build them off the standard tier structure (data layer, business rules / logic layer, UI layer). This will ensure that your logic code you want to test does not reference the form, but instead uses classes that are easily unit tested.

For a very basic example, don't have code that does this:

```c#
string str = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
//do whatever your code does
TextBox2.Text = str;
```

Instead extract the logic into a separate class with a method:

```c#
TextBox2.Text = DoWork(TextBox1.Text.ToString());

public class Work
{
    public string DoWork(string str)
    {
      //do work
      return str2;
    }
}
```

This way you can write unit tests to verify that DoWork is returning the correct values:

```c#
string return = DoWork("TestThisString");
```

Now all of your logic is unit testable, with only code that HAS to reference the page directly still in your UI layer.

Answer (score 10):

A very simple technique is the smoke test, where you automate a click-through of all of your application. If the script runs and there are no errors anywhere in the logs, you have at least one defined level of quality.

This technique actually catches a fair amount of regression breaks and is much more effective than it sounds like. We use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this.

Comment: Do you mean a functional testing with specific test scenarios or it's just - click every possible target?

Comment: The simplest version we do is to click through the use cases that are our main deliverables. At minimum we also include main alternate/error flows. This does not necessarily mean we'll click every button/item there is.

Answer (score 2):

[Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple checklist (even on a piece of paper!) is the best way to make sure you never skip the important things.  It's a good "smoke test" that nothing "standard" has been broken.